# Calculated Value Query with EFQ Hook

Tags: entities, hooks, forms, views

Using Entity Field Query, how can I use a hook to query by a calculated value? For example:

```
function mymodule_query_keyword_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
    $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_one', 'n', 'node.nid = n.entity_id');
    $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_two', 'l', 'node.nid = l.entity_id');
    $query->where("'n.field_one_value' * 'n.field_two_value' >= 40");
}
```

This shows the idea of what I want to do, but does not work.

Ideally I would also be able to sort my query by this value as well, **and extend this capability to performing a geolocation query**.